# Hard disks power down, even when set to "never" in "Power Options"

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, power-management

In Windows XP:

A few of my hard disk(s) power down occasionally, even when I have set them to "never" turn off, in the Control Panel's "Power Options", and even saved the new power-theme.

What do I need to do to stop sleep mode from occurring?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, but this is a programming QA site. Your question is off-topic here.

Comment: What drive? is it a 'Green' one?